Work and Express VPN conflict
I wonder if you could help me set up my 2 VPN's such that they do not conflict.
So, I have 1) express vpn and 2) a work vpn client.
Sometimes my work vpn client runs in the background and I forget about it, then I start up express vpn and at my job I can't connect to work services from abroad, so I get a strike and get banned from being able to use work services. I don't want that to happen anymore. So I was wondering if there is a way to prevent my work VPN from running, when express vpn is running, and prevent express vpn from running when my work vpn is running.

This is not something we can help you with, because we know nothing about the configuration of the work VPN, and that is likely the crucial factor. In this case the best advice we can give is to better separate your personal and work activities, by using different machines, VMs, etc.
